# share URL on whatsapp - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, whatsapp

I want to share iTunes URL of application on whatsapp via app.
I am using below code:

```
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hi, I am using test app. You can also download it from here %@",strUrl];
    NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    } else {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

But, I can't share it as it contains https url.
I have tried various solutions which I found on stackoverflow.

Is there any way to do that ?

--Updated:
I got the solution by converting the iTunes url to tinyURL.
Thanks for the help.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what does your code produce that you would like to change?

Comment: It shares nil. But if I remove https url, it will work perfectly.

Comment: What's `nil`? Please clarify your issue.

Comment: I mean it will share nothing if https is there in the string

Comment: You are still being far too vague. What actually happens? Is the whatsapp app actually launched or not? Do you see any message?

Comment: It will launch whatsapp image but am not able to share any text with link text

Comment: You must use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` only on the text you want to share, not the full URL.